# How to get first 5 digits of a 6 digit number

Tags: java

I got a task that I need a program to read a 6-digit number and in my way to the solution I faced a problem: I don't know how to get the first 5 digits of the input number.
**For Example:**
Input number: **123454**
Output: **12345**

I need to do it without substring function.

Comment: How the number is represented? `int`? `String`?

Comment: There is no way this is too broad!

Comment: Good luck on maman 11 mate ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
long small = (long) (yourNumber / 10);
```

Or

```
Math.floor(yourNumber / 10);
```

Comment: What type is `yourNumber`?

Answer (score 2):

You could store it as an integer and divide it by 10.

```
int num = 123454;
System.out.println(num/10);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for number of any length to 5

```
int length = String.valueof(inputnumber).length();
// or int length = inputnumber.length();
int retval = inputnumber/((int)Math.pow(10,length-5));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the last digit

```
int digit = 123454; 
digit = (int)digit/10;
```

Comment: he said **he mustn't use substring method**

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could just do

```
int number = 123454;
String textNum = ((Integer)number).toString();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < textNum.length()-1; i++) {
    sb.append(textNum.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

And create your own `substring()` functionality. People already said `number/10`.